How to make a handler on MDActionBottomAppBarButton
I am learning kivy and kivy md 2. I have a question, how to make a page change handler on MDActionBottomAppBarButton?
MDBottomAppBar:
                id: bottom_appbar
                allow_hidden: True
                action_items:
                    [
                    MDActionBottomAppBarButton(icon="arrow-u-left-top"),
                    MDActionBottomAppBarButton(icon="home"),
                    MDActionBottomAppBarButton(icon="magnify"),
                    ]

Tried using lambda, it gives an error. How to change the screen to the main page?

solved the problem, through the lambda with a function.
